# How to create an installable iso from my linux distro

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iso

I extremely customized Ubuntu to the core to create my own distro. But I don't know how to create an installable iso for it. Does anyone have an idea how?

Comment: Do you really need an ISO, or just good backups. Most settings are in /home, your installed apps can be listed and used to reinstall all of them. Only if you have installed server apps may you need some folders in / (root) for them.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem Best practice for Backups
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436006 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc & http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders

Answer (score 2):

Two steps:

1. Package your changes
2. Include your package in your iso

#### Designing the package

I expect your package to contain five things:

1. New configuration files
2. Scripted customizations to existing configuration files
3. Scripted commands
4. Required Dependencies
5. Convenient Dependencies

New configuration files are easy to install as part of a package.  Simply add them to your package.  If you've changed a file such as `/etc/sudoers` or `/etc/apt/sources.list`, try to put your changes in `/etc/sudoers.d/` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.  Don't deploy your own version of `/etc/sudoers` expecting it to override the version deployed by sudo. Your package will be in conflict and fail to install.

If you really need to make changes to an existing configuration file, add it to your `postinst` script.  Make an attempt to undo the change in the `prerm` script.  Here are some examples:

```
echo "192.168.1.1    router" >> /etc/hosts
sed 's/PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication no/' -i /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

If you need to run any commands (such as `useradd` or `realm`) then you should also do that in `postinst`.

You can also add dependencies to this package.  If you've made a change to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, then you probably want to depend on `openssh-server`  which ensures that file is installed before your script works on it. You can find which packages own each file with `dpkg -S /path/to/file`.

You can also add dependencies on packages you know you want in your custom config.  If you like chromium and know you'll want that installed everytime you use this image, then go ahead and add a dependency on chromium to avoid the need to manually `apt-get` later on.

### Making the package

Some tools you can use to make packages include [`dh_make`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/dh-make/dh_make.8.en.html) or [`cpack`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/CPackDeb.html).

`dh_make` will make a template for you so you can add the files you like and then use `dpkg-buildpackage` to produce the `*.deb` file.  Understanding all of the options is a little daunting and takes time to study and understand, but it's how native debian/ubuntu packages are produced.

`cpack` uses a `CMakeLists.txt` file to define the rules.  Add files to your package with the [`install()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/install.html) command and [`CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/CPackDeb.html#variable:CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA) will help you define your postinst.  I find `cpack` was easier to learn, especially for trivial packages.

Once you have a package, boot up a new Ubuntu (maybe use a chroot or vm), then test your package by installing it with `dpkg -i`.  If your system is how you want it, then you've succeeded.  Now you can take a basic ubuntu installation and customize it all by installing this single package.

### ISO packaging

But I see you want to go further...  You don't want to run that one command, you want to get this customization out-of-the-box.  You can!

You'll need to generate the installation disc in the same way Debian or Ubuntu does it, but add you're own package to the disk and set it to auto-install.

[Simple-CDD](https://wiki.debian.org/Simple-CDD/Howto) is probably the easiest tool to make a debian-based iso.  I'm not sure how well it works with Ubuntu though.  [LiveCD customization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization?action=show&redirect=LiveCDCustomization%2F6.06) sounds like the most likely solution there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had never heard of simple-cdd before. But I was actually considering Distroshare or Systemback. But both of those don't really work for me. I intend to release a full distro based on ubuntu. It's not that I am lazy but I was looking for a more easy and automated way to create an iso with an installer and stuff.

Comment: I think Simple-CDD or LiveCDcustomization are still the answers.