# How to create an installer for my custom distro?

Tags: ubuntu

I created an ubuntu based distro that is truly minimal. It involved taking ubuntu stripping it down to the bare minimum and then implementing my own desktop environment. I currently can create a livecd of it but how can I create an installer app for it since people can't really use it without installation. P.S. Can someone recommend me some good tags for this question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an installable iso from my linux distro](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/619196/how-to-create-an-installable-iso-from-my-linux-distro)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not creating a new installer from scratch but rather using an existing solution like [Calameres](https://calamares.io/). It's a distribution independent installer currently used by Manjaro, Lubuntu and others.

Or you can try adapting Ubiquity (Ubuntu installer) if your distro is Ubuntu based.

If you really want to create a new installer from scratch you'll need:

- something to setup the storage (create partitions and filesystems)
- something to install packages (or with Live CD this is usually done by copying the live system on the disk)
- something to create and configure user account(s)
- something to make the system boot (install bootloader, configure UEFI and configure initramfs)

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I already knew about calamares and ubiquity. It's just that I don't know how to use it to create an installer for my distro. I know it is not easy but I don't even know where to start.