# Releasing whole filesystem as Linux distro?

Tags: system-installation

I want to create a Linux distribution based on Arch. For now, I just created a script which does all the needed commands to install the system, such as pacstraping, copying configuration files etc.

I browsed the web looking for cleaner methods and found [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/620805/how-to-create-an-installer-for-my-custom-distro). Vojtech says

> something to install packages (or with Live CD this is **usually done by copying the live system** on the disk).

Does that mean I can just install Arch in a VM, configure everything, copy /, make an installer which just copies it to the destination computer and that's done? Or is it not possible because there are computer-specific files? If so, what did Vojtech mean?

Comment: Why not leave a comment on that thread?

Comment: The main reason is that it's a very old thread. And also, I think it's a question that deserve its own one, tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Leaving a comment won't hurt. You can also point them at this question. This question is fine though.

Comment: I'll do that thanks for the tip!
EDIT: I need 50 reputation to comment and I just created my account, rip xD

Comment: How will you boot your kernel?  You'll have to configure that, and that's beyond just copying files to disk.

Comment: Oh you're right, indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing packages is basically just extracting and copying data (there are some scripts involved in there but these too in the end only change the installed system) so you can replace that step by rsyncing the content of the LiveCD's root filesystem to the disk. That's why installation from a LiveCD doesn't download packages during installation (some installers can download and install updates during installation) unlike the small network-based installation images.

But that's definitely not all and I mentioned other steps in the answer. Some things can be done after the installation during the first boot, like creating the user account. But you still need to boot, which means installing and configuring the bootloader. You also need to writing some configuration files which will be specific for the new system (like `/etc/fstab` for example). And you also need to build the [initramfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk) image which is also customized for the hardware. You'd usually chroot to the system and do these steps in chroot.

tl ;dr When rsyncing the LiveCD you are replacing only the "install packages" steps from the  [Arch installation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/installation_guide), you still need to do the rest.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer!!